# Ethernet interface appears twice, how to fix?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ip, static-ip

**EDIT:** The static IP does not seem to be causing the problem. Even with default `/etc/network/interface` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` settings, and with wireless disabled, there still appears to be 2 ethernet interfaces: `Wired connection 1` and `enp2s0`. I cannot connect to internet when `enp2s0` is selected, and `enp2s0` is usally selected after restarting network manager. To fix this, I have to manually click `Wired connection 1`, and `enp2s0` disappears when I do this. **How do I fix this?**

Screenshot links (wireless disabled, default interfaces and network manager configuration):

[2 ethernet interfaces?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAmBO.png)

[Connects to enp2s0 after restart, which does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQTY7.png)

***New ifconfig***

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:1f:02:be  
          inet addr:192.168.0.218  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::54de:ea68:cbb:6181/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:106316 errors:0 dropped:13 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:89628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:57076040 (57.0 MB)  TX bytes:16214470 (16.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:36420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36420 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:3387717 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:3387717 (3.3 MB)
```

---

**Before edit:**
I am using Ubuntu 16.04. The static IP is working, but the Ethernet interface seems to appear twice as `enp2s0` (does not work) and `ifupdown(enp2s0)`. I have also set up static IP for the wireless interface, but it does not have this problem.

The computer occasionally connects to `enp2s0` mysteriously, especially after `network.service` is restarted. I get an error that says something similar to "This webpage cannot be found", which looks like a DNS issue. To fix this, I have to either click on `ifupdown(enp2s0)` on the top right or run `sudo ifdown enp2s0` then `sudo ifup enp2s0`. Once connected to `ifupdown(enp2s0)`, `enp2s0` disappears. Why is this happening  and how do I prevent it?

To set the static IP, I first changed `/etc/network/interfaces` to allow the Ethernet and wireless interface to have static IPs. I went to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and set `[ifupdown] managed=true`.

***/etc/network/interfaces***

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# The loopback network interface
iface lo inet loopback

# Assign static IP
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.218
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.218
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

***/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf***

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

***ip link***

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:2c:4a:1f:02:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state   DOWN       mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:cf:5e:27:2b:6a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

***ifconfig***

```
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:2c:4a:1f:02:be  
          inet addr:192.168.0.218  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3b69:a581:1b73:66f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:77581 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:39317309 (39.3 MB)  TX bytes:12189434 (12.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:30000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30000 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2840650 (2.8 MB)  TX bytes:2840650 (2.8 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:cf:5e:27:2b:6a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:83028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:86707469 (86.7 MB)  TX bytes:8884239 (8.8 MB)
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your `interfaces` file asks *both* ethernet and wireless to start automatically and to use the same IP address. As the wireless stanza is defective, as it doesn't specify the SSID or password, no doubt the system is confused.

I suggest that you remove all the additions you made to `interfaces` and revert NetworkManager.conf to `managed=no`.

Then, simply set your static IP address in Network Manager, like this:

[image]

Of course, substitute your addresses here.

**EDIT**: In order to stop the "ghost" entry, I suggest that you delete all previous connections. From the terminal:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

Comment: Ok I restored everything to default setting. Even with DHCP, the "ghost" interface still remains. I have wireless disabled. The ethernet interfaces are: `Wired connection 1` and `enp2s0`. In several cases after restarting, the computer will connect to the ghost interface, and the internet wouldn't work. I have to manually select `Wired connection 1`, then the "ghost" disappears and everything works. Why does this happen and how do I fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/vdi8Gkx.png

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ghost connection `enp2s0` still appears after deleting the system-connections and after restarting the network manager. If I use `enp2s0` instead of wired connection, the internet doesn't work. Once I click on wired connection, `enp2s0` disappears, and everything works. Is this normal behaviour after restarting the network manager? It's annoying because the internet doesn't work, but it's survivable.

Comment: Here's a link of the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/g0Z2ztg.png . You can see the double ethernet connections on the top right.

Comment: It is not normal behavior. I have no other suggestions to offer. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions anyways, they did help show a cleaner way to define static IPs rather than editing config files, I appreciate your time.